# what causes youtube old comment section

Tags: javascript, youtube

some channels still seem to have the old comment system. im trying to create a script that makes every comment section be like that.
it can be seen on videos like this: youtube.com/watch?v=oV27GvzUE-k

the html is a bit different than at normal comment sections, but when i copied and pasted the html in the place of a removed new comment section (with Customize your web), it still turns into the new one.

i know it SHOULD be possible to get the old style back, because if i paste the video url (for example tPEE9ZwTmy0) in the url used to open the comment frames from, it looks like the new one. for example:
a new style comment frame : https://apis.google.com/u/0/wm/4/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&first_party_property=YOUTUBE&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DtPEE9ZwTmy0
the video url of the example video i gave that has the old comment system, pasted at the end of the url above:
https://apis.google.com/u/0/wm/4/_/widget/render/comments?usegapi=1&first_party_property=YOUTUBE&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DoV27GvzUE-k

so the comments are probably "render"ed differently in the first place. its not even in a frame when it looks like the old one, but it can be opened like that too.
so i would be grateful if someone would tell me what causes a video to have the old style of comment section.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not front end, it's the backend of the website that changes the comment system, you could write some CSS, but you couldn't change the functionality of it.

Comment: but the comments are the same. if you open the old-looking comments the way you open the new ones' frame, it works the same way the current ones do. so only the presentation/calling of the comments should be different. which should be on the page somewhere. just try the links i posted above. the comments are not different, its just how they are shown. i need help determining what causes this

Comment: @KovácsJános, it's back end, as I've said, along with other aspects, the comments are stored differently - there is nothing you can do (unless you work at Google).

Comment: why would they be stored differently if i can open them literally the same way the new ones look? same ordering, same everything. if its opened that way, the google+ comments become visible, otherwise they arent there.